# Eight videos, three minutes long each; enough time for five. How many combinations?

Tags: combinatorics

> Justin has 8 videos, all approximately 3 minutes long, but only has time to watch 5 of them. How many different combinations of these five videos can he watch?

$$5V3= \frac{5!}{(5-3)!}=\frac{5!}{2!}=\frac{120}2=60$$

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: The notation $\binom{5}{3}$ represents the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) counting the number of size-3 subsets there are from a 5-element set (*or in the less precise phrasing, the number of ways of choosing 3 objects where order doesn't matter*).  It evaluates algebraically instead to $\binom{5}{3}=\dfrac{5!}{\color{red}{3!}(5-3)!}=10$.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect whether order matters or not.  Are you simply interested in which videos Justin selects or the sequence in which he watches them?  I suspect that the meaning of your answer was changed during an edit since the expression $\binom{5}{3} \neq \frac{5!}{(5 - 3)!}$.

Comment: On the other hand $5\frac{3}{~}$ or $~_5P_3$ or $P(5,3)$ or however you prefer to notate it is the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) counting number of ways to arrange 3 objects in a line out of 5 available objects.  You would have had $5\frac{3}{~}=\frac{5!}{(5-3)!}=60$.  Sadly, neither of these numbers are relevant to the question you are being asked.  You have eight available videos of which he watches five.  (*the number 3 is completely irrelevant to the problem and is only there for flavor*).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that Justin is selecting five of the eight videos, not three of five.

Let's distinguish between two questions.

> In how many ways can Justin watch five of the eight videos?

Justin can choose the first video in eight ways, the second video in seven ways (from the remaining videos), the third video in six ways, the fourth video in five ways, and the fifth video in four ways.  Hence, he can watch five of the eight videos in
$$8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 = 6720$$
ways.

This is an example of a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) problem since the order in which the videos are watched matters.

Observe that we could write the answer in the following form
$$8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 = \frac{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = \frac{8!}{3!} = \frac{8!}{(8 - 5)!}$$

In general, the number of ways of selecting $k$ items from $n$ items when the order of selection matters is 
$$P(n, k) = \frac{n!}{(n - k)!}$$

> In how many ways can Justin select five of the eight videos to watch?

In this case, we do not care about the order in which the videos are selected, so we divide the answer above by the $5!$ orders in which Justin could select the same five videos.  Thus, the number of ways Justin could select five of the eight videos to watch is 
$$\frac{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4}{5!} = \frac{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4}{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = \frac{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6}{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = 8 \cdot 7 = 56$$

Notice that we could express the answer in the form
$$\frac{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4}{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = \frac{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1  \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = \frac{8!}{5!3!}$$

This is an example of a [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) problem since the order in which the videos are selected does not matter, just which subset of videos is selected.

The number of ways of selecting a subset of $k$ elements from a set with $n$ elements is 
$$C(n, k) = \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$